# How can I improve this inner join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

My database has 3 tables. One is called Customer, one is called Orders, and one is called RMA. The RMA table has the info regarding returns. I'll include a screen shot of all 3 so you can see the appropriate attributes. This is the code of the query I'm working on:

`SELECT State, SKU, count(*)
from Orders INNER JOIN Customer ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customer.CustomerID
INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.Order_ID  = RMA.Reason
Group by SKU
Order by SKU
LIMIT 10;`

I'm trying to get how much of each product(SKU) is returned in each state(State). Any help would really be appreciated. I'm not sure why, but anytime I include a JOIN statement, my query takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 20 minutes to process.

[image: Orders table][ Customer table]

![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJoPE.png)[ RMA table]

![3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7CgK.png)

Comment: This condition doesn’t look right: Orders.Order_ID  = RMA.Reason. Îs teasing the sale as order_id?

Comment: Please create a dbfiddle using the exact create statements of your tables and sample data. Otherwise it would be hard to help you.

Comment: What's the size of the data, can you tell us how many rows are in Orders, Customers, and RMA? Are there any indexes on these tables?

Comment: I'd like to add that somehow, the Reason and OrderID column  on the RMA table got mixed up, so the reason column holds the information for each order id.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.State, o.SKU, COUNT(*)
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN
     Customer c
     ON o.Customer_ID = c.CustomerID JOIN
     RMA
     ON o.Order_ID = RMA.Order_Id
GROUP BY c.State, o.SKU
ORDER BY SKU;
```

Your issue is probably the incorrect `JOIN` condition between `Orders` and `RMA`.

If you have primary keys properly declared on the tables, then this query should have good-enough performance.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are joining with an Orders table I'm going to assume this table contains all the orders that the company has ever done. This can be quite large and would likely cause the slowness you are seeing.

You can likely improve this query if you place some constraint on the Orders you are selecting, restricting what date range you use is common way to do this. If you provide more information about what the query is for and how large the dataset is everyone will be able to provide better guidance as to what filters would work best.

Comment: I tried adding a LIMIT statement, do you think that helped at all? Is there some way I could add a WHERE statement to this query, like narrow it down to 5 states or something like that?

Comment: I don't think limit is helpful for your use case is it simply truncate data, so you would have missing data. A WHERE clause is exactly what I was referring to with filters. Place the WHERE before the aggregation functions (group by, order by) and after the join statements. When building and testing new queries filtering by the smallest thing is often helpful purely because you get some of the data back and you can verify the main query on the subset you are returning before running it for all the states in your case.